# Foundation 5 Tabs - content is not filling width of tab container

Tags: html, css, zurb-foundation

I have a web page where I am using the Foundation 5 tabs.  The problem is that some of the tab's content does not fill the width of the container. (i used images for the code examples because it was easier to summarize the code)

### EXAMPLE #1

**THIS WORKS:**

For example, this code works correctly and the tab content fills the tab container's width (note the code for tab panel4):

**HTML Code:**

[image]

**HTML Display:**

[image]

### EXAMPLE # 2

**THIS DOES NOT WORK:**

The following html code for the tabs displays the content, but the tab's content does not "fill" the width of the container like the example above (code for tab panel 1).

**HTML code:**

[image]

**HTML Display:**

[image]

Notice how the tab content is not as wide as the first example.

### QUESTION:

I need help trouble shooting this so that the tab content (a fieldset) fills the width of the tab container. I hope this makes sense.  I can post the full code for download if anyone wishes. I tried to keep is as short as possible.

Thanks in advance for you help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bahh, I was over thinking it, there was a simple css fix:

I had to add the following to an override.css file I use to augment the foundation.min.css file

```
.tabs-content > .content {
    width: 100%;
}
```